# Return all states across time-steps in RNN in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm implementing my own recurrent layer in Keras, and inside the `step` function I would like to have access to the hidden states across all time steps, not just the last state as by default, so that I could do stuff like adding skip connections backwards in time.

I'm trying to modify `_step` inside `K.rnn` in the tensorflow backend to return all hidden states so far. My initial thought was to simply store each hidden state to a TensorArray, and then pass all of those to the `step_function` (i.e. the `step` function in my layer). My current modified function is the following, which writes each hidden state into a TensorArray `states_ta_t`:

```
   def _step(time, output_ta_t, states_ta_t, *states):
            current_input = input_ta.read(time)
            # Here I'd like to return all states up to current time
            # and pass to step_function, instead of just the last
            states = [states_ta_t.read(time)]
            output, new_states = step_function(current_input,
                                               tuple(states) +
                                               tuple(constants))
            for state, new_state in zip(states, new_states):
                new_state.set_shape(state.get_shape())
            states_ta_t = states_ta_t.write(time+1, new_states[0]) # record states
            output_ta_t = output_ta_t.write(time, output)
            return (time + 1, output_ta_t, states_ta_t) + tuple(new_states)
```

This version only returns the last state, just like the original implementation, and works as a normal RNN. How can I take all the states so far, stored in the array, and pass to the `step_function`? It feels like this should be incredibly simple, but I'm not very well versed using TensorArrays...

(Note: this is easier to do in the unrolled version rather than the symbolic one, but unfortunately I would run out of memory using the unrolled version for my experiments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- Edited --

I find that I've misunderstood your question, I'm terribly sorry for that...

In short, try this:

```
states = states_ta_t.stack()[:time]
```

Here's some explaination: you indeed have all those states stored in `states_ta_t`, but you only passed the last one to your `step_function`.

What you've done in your code is :

```
# Param 'time' refers to 'current time step'
states = [states_ta_t.read(time)]
```

Which means that you're reading the 'current' state from `states_ta_t`, in other word, the last state.

If you want to do some slicing instead, maybe [`stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray#stack) function will help. For example:

```
states = states_ta_t.stack()[:time]
```

But I'm not sure whether this is a proper implementation, since I'm not familiar with TensorArray either...

Hope it helps! If it doesn't, it's my honor if you are willing to leave comments and discuss with me!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer]
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll read it and try hard to improve my answers :)

Comment: Thanks very much @Carefree0910 . That answers my question, I didn't know I could slice them in that way :-) I realised in the end that I might be using too much memory this way, by keeping all states at once in states_ta_t. So I ended up creating two TensorArrays, one for the current time-step and one the previous time-step, with "clear_after_read=True", this way I only get access to one state extra back in time, but only two states are kept in memory at any time.

Comment: @jodles You're welcome, and I should thank you too since your solution inspired me ;-)